# Multiple definition of "~~" first defined here error

Tags: c++

I'm trying to test one of my function I've written but I keep getting this error. I've searched places and they all say use "extern" or something of the like, but it doesn't seem like either its not working, or I'm not doing it right.

This is the .h file:

```
#ifndef BOGGLEUTIL_H
#define BOGGLEUTIL_H

#include <string>
#include <vector>

class TST;
class bogNode;
class BoggleUtil{
  public:
  static void insertWords(const std::vector<std::string> &word_list, int counter,
                   int startR, int startL, int start, TST& t);

};

class TST {
  private:
    /**
     * Returns negative if b < c
     * 0 if b == c, positive if b > c 
     */
    int charCmp(char b, char c);

  protected:
    bogNode* root;

  public:
    /**
     * Inserts a string into the ternary tree
     */
    void insert(const std::string word);
};

/**
 * A sick-ass node for a sick-ass tree
 */
class bogNode{
  public:
    // Constructor goes here
    bogNode(const char &c): data(c) {
      data = c;
      left = right = center = nullptr;
      end = false;
    }


  //private:
    bogNode* left;    // Children nodes
    bogNode* right;
    bogNode* center;
    char data;    // Data contained in node
    bool end;              // True if node is an end node
};

#endif // BOGGLEUTIL_H
```

This is part of my .cpp file:

```
#include "boggleutil.h"
#include <iostream>

void BoggleUtil::insertWords(const std::vector<std::string>& word_list, int counter,
               int startR, int startL, int start, TST& t)
{
...
}


int TST::charCmp(char b, char c){
    return ((int) b - c);
}

void TST::insert(const std::string word) 
{
...
}
```

And this is my main I wrote up for a simple testing purpose:

```
#include "boggleutil.cpp"
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int
main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  std::vector<std::string> test;
  test.push_back("test1");
  test.push_back("test2");
  test.push_back("test3");
  test.push_back("test4");
  test.push_back("test5");
  test.push_back("test6");
  test.push_back("test7");
  test.push_back("test8");
  test.push_back("test9");
  test.push_back("test10");
  test.push_back("test11");
  test.push_back("test12");
  test.push_back("test13");
  test.push_back("test14");
  test.push_back("test15");
  test.push_back("test16");
  test.push_back("test17");
  test.push_back("test18");
  test.push_back("test19");
  test.push_back("test20");

  int counter = test.size()/2;
  int start = counter;
  int l = counter - counter/2;
  int r = counter + counter/2;

  TST t;

  BoggleUtil::insertWords(test, counter, r, l, start, t);
}
```

And lastly, this is the error report I'm getting with the compiler:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -g boggleutil.cpp boggleutil.h maintest.cpp
/tmp/ccTcJDhf.o: In function `__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::string>::new_allocator()':
/home/linux/ieng6/cs100w/bhn013/P4/boggleutil.cpp:5: multiple definition of `BoggleUtil::insertWords(std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> > const&, int,     int, int, int, TST&)'
/tmp/ccu0bhaW.o:/home/linux/ieng6/cs100w/bhn013/P4/boggleutil.cpp:5: first defined here
/tmp/ccTcJDhf.o: In function `TST::charCmp(char, char)':
/home/linux/ieng6/cs100w/bhn013/P4/boggleutil.cpp:62: multiple definition of `TST::charCmp(char, char)'
/tmp/ccu0bhaW.o:/home/linux/ieng6/cs100w/bhn013/P4/boggleutil.cpp:62: first defined here
/tmp/ccTcJDhf.o: In function `TST::insert(std::string)':
/home/linux/ieng6/cs100w/bhn013/P4/boggleutil.cpp:66: multiple definition of `TST::insert(std::string)'
/tmp/ccu0bhaW.o:/home/linux/ieng6/cs100w/bhn013/P4/boggleutil.cpp:66: first defined here
```

I have the slightest clue as to why this error keeps showing up. Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you find yourself `#include`-ing a .cpp file, stop. you're doing something *wrong*.

Answer (score 2):

You include the cpp:

```
#include "boggleutil.cpp"
```

This way the linker links two times the `BoggleUtil::insertWords(std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> > const&, int,     int, int, int, TST&)`

Once in your `boggleutil.cpp` and then in `maintest.cpp`